# Loading files to SAS Stored Process server using VBA

Tags: excel, sas, http-post, vba

Is there a way of (programmatically) sending files directly to the STP server via HTTP?  It appears that the [documented](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/61271/PDF/default/stpug.pdf) approach (using `<input type="file">`) cannot be used in an automated fashion, due to an explicit browser restriction designed to prevent spamming of web servers.

I don't wish to use the IOM (although we have AMO licensed) as this creates a dependency on a local SAS installation.

The current approach involves writing out to a shared directory and then calling an STP via a [web query](http://bi-notes.com/2013/02/sas-stored-processes-querying-a-stored-process-from-excel-without-the-add-in/) - which then lifts and drops the data to a non-shared location.

The issue is that the data is then in the wider corporate domain for those few seconds..  Would be much tidier to upload directly to SAS!

Is it possible though?  Without third party software (just vanilla excel VBA)?

Comment: I'm lost.  You want to programmatically upload a file from your PC to the stored process server.  Why do you want to do this via HTTP?  Couldn't you just SFTP or similar?  If you're making a web app for user to upload files and process them, then yes with HTTP the user would need to click through the process.  Unless you want to get into scripting your browser with something like http://imacros.net/overview.

Comment: I've built a data editor in excel, and need to send the records back to the SAS server.  I was indeed looking to script the browser, but without any local installs.  I think your are right, my only real option is to use SFTP (would need to set this up).  Would this prevent other users from viewing the files though?

Comment: It would depend on the permissions on your server, and where you put the files.

Comment: I think what you want is possible.  I just recently finished some code using jQuery/AJAX that would take a programmatically created data, and upload it to a SAS/Intrnet server (equivalent of the STP I believe) in a way that was compatible with the details on page 145 here ( https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/dispatch/62562/PDF/default/dispatch.pdf ).  If you are familiar with javascript you could have excel call some javascript instead of VBA. Alternatively there may be a way to do the equivalent using the Internet explorer automation object and VBA.

Comment: And for what it is worth, I don't see how the STP could tell the difference between a programmatically generated HTTP request and a regular HTML `<input type="file">` approach.  It should all look the same to the server...

Comment: Gonna rebuild the whole thing in the browser now..  But this does look like the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it is possible to do what you want, but I did see this and wonder if background mode would make a difference.

http://support.sas.com/kb/39/114.html

Comment: The _ACTION=BACKGROUND option allows the STP to run asynchronously (in the background).  My question is about passing a file to an STP - so this precedes the running of the STP itself.  Agreed though,  am not convinced it is possible to do what I want either!

Comment: I read your post again and I think I have a better idea of what you need to do.  sorry, but I know very little about VBA, so I can't help you there.  I think that AMO could help if you are able to install it on the clients.  I'd guess that you know this, but in case there's any confusion, the SAS Add-in does not put a full SAS install on the client, just the pieces necessary to communicate w/the server.  It's not too big of an install.  I wish I could be more help.

Comment: The issues we have with AMO is that we currently have 2 (and soon 3) versions of SAS to consider (which means different sets of VBA references), plus different versions of excel in use.  Also, it's very slow! Thanks though